# $E[Z]$ when $X$ follows an exponential distribution and $Z = \exp\{X\}$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

I am trying to find the expected value of an exponential distrubtion $E(Z)$. I am told $X$ is exponential distributed with the parameter $\lambda = 4$, and I am told $Z = \exp(X)$. I am having trouble solving for the density function of $Z$, even though I know the form of the density function for $X$.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to find the distribution function of $Z$. By the Law of the Unconscious Statistician,
$$E(Z)=\int_0^\infty (e^x)(\lambda e^{-\lambda x})\,dx.$$
In our case we are integrating $4e^{-3x}$.

Answer (score 2):

> How to find the density of $Z$?

Notice that $Z = \exp\{X\}$ is stricly increasing, and hence we can use the one-to-one change of variable; $X = \log Z$ and
$$f_Z(z) = \frac{f_X(\log z)}{\left|\frac{dz}{dx}\right|_{\log z}}.$$

Or you can use the cdf method and compute
$$P(Z\leq z) = P(\exp\{X\}\leq z).$$

---

> How to find $E[Z]$?

To compute the expectation of $Z$, you can proceed as usual. Let $g(X) = \exp\{X\}$. Then
$$E[Z] = E[\exp\{X\}] =\int_0^\infty g(x)\cdot f_X(x)\,dx = \int_0^\infty e^x\cdot \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx.$$

It is also possible to find the density of $Z$ above and do the the usual $E[Z]$.